# What causes Vue 2 to check a "get" function/property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My recent work in Vue (we're still using Vue 2 unfortunately) has caused me to question my understanding of how Vue checks property values and re-renders.

I've got a couple of components on my page which have a v-show clause tied to a get statement in the code:

```
<my-component v-show="this.isRequired">

public get isRequired(): boolean {

    if(this.model.myBooleanProperty == true && this.model.myNumberProperty > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    
    if(this.model.myOtherBooleanProperty == true && this.model.myOtherNumberProperty > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Now, my understanding is that Vue would check this function whenever any of the involved properties changed. So if the values of any out of `myBooleanProperty`, `myNumberProperty`, `myOtherBooleanProperty` and `myOtherNumberProperty` changed then `isRequired` would be checked and the `v-show` clause would cause the component to show or not show depending on the outcome.

However, I've learned this isn't the case. By commenting out parts of the function, it seems that only changes to `myBooleanProperty`, `myNumberProperty`, `myOtherBooleanProperty` ever cause `isRequired` to be checked, even if they're taken out of the function. `myOtherNumberProperty` never causes it to be checked, even if it's directly manipulated in `isRequired` by setting it to zero or null.

Can someone please explain what, under these circumstances, causes Vue to reevaluate the value of `isRequired`?

Comment: Make sure there is a property named `myOtherNumberProperty` declared and initialized in data function. if you start assigning to non existing properties, Vue won't keep track of them.

Comment: @MatJ we don't have a data function.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use `this` in the template, it's not necessary.
2. I understand you use [`vue-property-decorator`](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) library, right? Cause a `get x` property is a class getter, which is compiled down to a Vue [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) property.
3. You are right, computed properties react and reevaluate whenever one of their reactive dependency updates. `myOtherNumberProperty` should also trigger the computed to reevaluate its value.

Maybe you have a reactivity problem with this property. Check that this value is properly initialized in your `data` function. If it's missing in the initial `model` object, Vue won't make it reactive and thus, its changes won't trigger anything.

I can't help further more without additional context on your code.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I'm not sure what's going on here. This is legacy code and no one currently working at the company really understands it any more. I can't see any import statements anywhere for vue-class-decorator - I don't know what else it might be called? We also don't use data functions anywhere.

Comment: Actually it's `vue-property-decorator`, based on `vue-class-property` library, sorry for the confusion. You have a `@Component` decorator in the classes isn't it?

Comment: Yes, we've got that decorator. Thanks for clarifying.